# Why forced inline function was not implemented on Mac with clang++?

Tags: c++, macros, inline, compiler-optimization

**Update 2.0**

Thanks for many's great advice =-]

Here comes the newest update:

I tried to run four versions of addition: direct computation, macro function, forced inline and normal function call and compare their performance. The previous test was criticized as looping through 1000000000 (1e9) times spend most of the time on the loop rather than the function call. Therefore, this time I only loop for 10000 times, and within each loop, hard-code 10000 times of addition, to make sure most of the time is spent on the addition part.

The results are as follow:

```
    Compile: (-o2 optimization)
      clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o2 test.cpp -o a
    Output:
      Option 1: Direct compute  time    194342
      Option 2: Macro function  time    193176
      Option 3: Function call   time    516155
      Option 4: Forced inline   time    495453

    Compile: (-o3 optimization)
     clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o3 test.cpp -o a
    Output:
      Option 1: Direct compute  time    200816
      Option 2: Macro function  time    192981
      Option 3: Function call   time    504793
      Option 4: Forced inline   time    505626

    Compile: (-o4 optimization)
      clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o4 test.cpp -o a
    Output:
      Option 1: Direct compute  time    197561
      Option 2: Macro function  time    195808
      Option 3: Function call   time    509215
      Option 4: Forced inline   time    502218
```

It seems:

1. The forced inline was ignored by the compiler.
2. Different levels of optimization did not affect the running time.

I am curious of why the forced inline `__attribute__((always_inline))` was ignored by the compiler?

And codes are here:

```
    #define Add(a, b) (a)+(b)

    int add(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
    }

    static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int in_add(const int& a, const int& b) {
      return a+b;
    }

    int main(){
      int a;
      high_resolution_clock::time_point start, end;

      //Option 1

      a = 1;
      start = high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) if (a%100000){
        a = a + 1246;
        //repeat 10000 times
        a = a + 1246;
      }
      end = high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(  end - start ).count();
      cout<< "Option 1: Direct compute\ttime\t" << duration << '\n';

      //Option 2

      a = 1;
      start = high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) if (a%100000){
        a = Add(a, 1246);
        //repeat 10000 times
        a = Add(a, 1246);
      }
      end = high_resolution_clock::now();
      duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(  end - start ).count();
      cout<< "Option 2: Macro function\ttime\t" << duration << '\n';

      //Option 3

      a = 1;
      start = high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) if (a%100000){
        a = add(a, 1246);
        //repeat 10000 times
        a = add(a, 1246);
      }
      end = high_resolution_clock::now();
      duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(  end - start ).count();
      cout<< "Option 3: Function call \ttime\t" << duration << '\n';

      //Option 4

      a = 1;
      start = high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) if (a%100000){
        a = in_add(a, 1246);
        //repeat 10000 times
        a = in_add(a, 1246);
      }
      end = high_resolution_clock::now();
      duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(  end - start ).count();
      cout<< "Option 4: Forced inline \ttime\t" << duration << '\n';

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Did you turn optimizations on?

Comment: Can you post a test harness which produces results for all four cases one after the other, rather than requiring recompilation? Also, as @Galik points out, what optimizations have you turned on?

Comment: The proportion of time spent on the addition operation is so negligible with respect to the whole measured time that you cannot draw meaningful conclusions. You need to design a test that really *focuses* the measure on the compared operation, and you will surely find that, for example, macros are *exactly* a direct operation. So should be inlining, unless there are compiler specifics that prevented it.

Comment: Also, a rather direct and simpler method of comparison would be to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) if (a%100000){...` basically means the driver of execution time is the loop itself, rather than the actual operations being tested.   Unless, of course, the compiler is aggressive enough to optimise the loop itself.

Comment: What you're measuring is mostly loop overhead when what you appear to want is to measure function call overhead. One way to do that would be to code 100 or 1000 or 1000000 calls to your function inside each iteration of the loop (cut-and-paste is your friend :-) which will help factor out the loop overhead.

Comment: @TianchiCai the comments of Peter and Bob are what I meant. Also, again, why not look directly at the assembly code? If you dont find *exactly* the same code for *direct, macro and inline* then  you will have scored a big goal, indeed :P

Comment: @A.S.H I see the point. Let me try for the assembly code and thank you for the kind explanation  =-]

Comment: 1. change the order of tests, see if it changes anything. 2. look at assembly. Most probably, `const int&` gets translated to `const int*` in the bg (i.e., it's not binding, it's taking address of on Itanium ABI). When you take the address of a variable, it can't remain it a register.

Comment: @lorro the compiler (after optimization) should not need to take the address to use a reference argument of an *inlined* function.

Comment: (concerning update 2.0) Well, the test strongly confirms the "null hypothesis" that macro and direct are the two sides of the same coin :relieved:. On the other hand, in the inlined version, it seems like clang has ignored the directive for some reason.

Comment: Or probably it expanded it differently than expected. Examining the generated assembly will be interesting (I'm not familiar with clang).